# Wordpress: How to setup /blog/post-title permalink?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WP instance installed at root. I want to put blog posts in a tag or category (whichever is best) such that they would be accessed via:

```
domain.tld/blog/post-title
```

This is probably super easy, but the only way I can this to work is with 'category' (or some other word) in the permalink like so:

```
domain.tld/category/blog/post-title
```

I'm sure this is dead simple. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, I believe you just need to go to wp-admin => settings => Permalinks and add the Custom Structure of

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Comment: No problem. If your problem has been solved, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks!